# what is wrong with this python code to get a set of primes between 2 to 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
prime=set()
for i in range(2,10):
    for j in range(2,i):
        if (i%j==0):
            break
        else:
            prime.add(i)
print(prime)
#yields {9,3,5,7},which is concerning....
```

I changed the range values, but it didn't budge; actually got worse.

I know very well that there are other methods to obtain prime nos. , just try to stick to this format and try to rectify it if you can

Comment: `else:` is at the wrong indentation. It should be one level out, so you only add to `prime` if you get through the entire loop.

Comment: Because of that you add all odd numbers to `prime`.

Comment: Just one more question, why does 9 fail the i % j == 0 test? Shouldn't it be satisfied when j = 3?

Comment: You never get that far. You add it when `i == 2`, then break when `i == 3`.

Comment: Ahhhh, forgot about the break statement, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

As other people have commented @Barmar, @Kelly:

You can use `for-else` combination. It is one of the beautiful features of python.

Once the inner `for loop` is exhausted `else` clause will be executed.

Your same code just to indent `else` at the level of for.

*printing prime till 99*

```
prime=set()
for i in range(2,100):
    for j in range(2,i):
        if (i%j==0):
            break
    else:
        prime.add(i)
print(prime)

#output
{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97}
```

[for-else documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)